# Округление углов RelativeLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Доброго времени суток. 
Я пытаюсь округлить углы в модального окна, которое будет появляться, но проблема, я не могу округлить все слои одновременно.
Есть: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_height="210dp"
    android:background="@drawable/modal_dialog_background"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:paddingRight="110dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:scaleY="2"
        android:src="@drawable/login_circle"
        android:id="@+id/imageView3" />


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingRight="120dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_popup_phone"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="PHONE"
        android:textColor="@color/colorText"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="(0382)0000\n5546561561\n067 178 06 011"
        android:textColor="@color/colorButtonPressed"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.5"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Нужно: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

login_circle.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:bottom="10dp"
        android:top="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:left="10dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <size android:height="500dp" android:width="500dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@color/colorCircleBackground" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <stroke
                android:width="4dp"
                android:color="#4d4d4d" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Проблема в округленных углах слева.
Спасибо, если хоть взглянули на проблему)

Comment: код drawable/login_circle покажешь?

Comment: ах да, забыл еще - разметку relativelayout саму не покажешь? а то тут не понятно как ты сейчас скругляешь углы справа

Comment: drawable/modal_dialog_background скорей всего перекрывает ваш рисунок, попробуйте убрать.

Comment: Так его то и нужно оставить)

Answer (score 2):

а если у RelativeLayout на background поставить такое, разве не будет работать?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <corners android:radius="15dp" />

</shape>
```

Comment: увы не работает)
в моей розметке есть такие же строки